# Why am I getting list of lists as output for model.predict in keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

My output when using a model.predict with my test set is shown below. Whereas the accuracy from my epochs was in the 0.8 range.

```
`[[1.63658711e-04 9.99836326e-01]
[2.59015225e-02 9.74098504e-01]
[9.78065059e-02 9.02193546e-01]
[1.09802298e-02 9.89019811e-01]
[3.25678848e-04 9.99674320e-01]
[3.48023442e-03 9.96519804e-01]
[1.56172812e-02 9.84382689e-01]
[4.83522518e-03 9.95164752e-01]
[6.11863611e-03 9.93881345e-01]
[3.42085288e-04 9.99657869e-01]
[5.51505107e-03 9.94484961e-01]...]'
```

My aim is to predict whether a person has heart disease or not, how do I compare the values of my test set and my true values and find out the performance of my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code I am assuming you are classifying between two classes. The two outputs are the probability that the inferenced data is one class or the other.

`[1.63658711e-04 9.99836326e-01]`

This shows us that it thinks that the probability of class 1 is .000163658 (.0163658%) and class 2 .999836 (99.836%).

I'm guessing that class 1 is heart disease and class 2 is not heart disease based on the number of each.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used a threshold of 0.7 to classify them into 0 or 1 and got it to work.